# Noise Temperature of Antenna

Tags: noise

A microwave receiving antenna on a satellite is pointing towards the earth. The antenna beamwidth is 50 degrees, the earth subtends 5 degrees at the satellite. What will be the noise temperature of the antenna?

P.S. Is the data enough to find the noise temperature of the antenna ??  That is one objective of the question, to verify enough data is here before solving it.

The formula NF = 10*log10(NoiseTemp/290 +1) , NF=SNR(input) in dB - SNR(output) in dB is inapplicable here , I have tried with that only ! Also, it seems that in the question some data is incomplete, need to focus on the incompleteness of the question also.

Comment: How have you tried to solve it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework with no attempt at an answer.

Comment: This question has been already tried to be solved. Only thing is to know that is the data enough for finding out the noise temperature or not . Updating the question as-well .

Comment: So, you didn't really tell us anything about your attempt in your update. Please show us what you've considered.

Comment: *Show your work so far*.  If you're totally lost, say so.  Do you know the definition of the noise temperature of a source?

Comment: The formula NF = 10*log10(NoiseTemp/290 +1) , NF=SNR(input) in dB - SNR(output) in dB is inapplicable here , I have tried with that only !

Comment: Please edit the question with your efforts.

Comment: @TimWescott Kindly help to get a concrete answer or please comment on the incompleteness in finding the answer.

Comment: Kindly stop saying "kindly" before I blow a fuse.  It's like saying "would you **please** finally do this simple thing as I have ordered you to do, but which you are seemingly to incompetent or lazy to accomplish."

Comment: I asked if you knew the *definition* of the *noise temperature* of a source, and you replied with the definition of the noise **figure** of a source.  From which I assume that you either cannot get onto Wikipedia and type "noise temperature" in the search bar to find [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_temperature), or that you are like a 2-day old chick shrieking at mom with it's mouth open.  Do more than shriek.  Do some work.

Comment: Read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_temperature), come back here, and kindly tell us why you can or cannot calculate the total noise power at your antenna output given the information you have available to you.

Comment: ................

Comment: @TimWescott 

I have tried using the formula : \$\Delta_T\$\$=\$\$T_{earth}\$\$*\$(\$\Omega_S\$\$/\$\$\Omega_A\$\$)\$ where \$T_{earth}\$ is the noise temperature of earth taken as \$290\$ \$K\$ and \$\Delta_T\$ is the difference in noise temperature of earth and the antenna . But the exact bandwidth of antenna is missing , only said it works in the microwave range . No information is also given about sidelobes too .

Comment: So is this can be inferred that data is inadequate ? That is also part of my question . The noise figure calculation if possible , is an alternative way to find out noise temperature from the given question's data  , so that has been referred here .

Comment: You can find an equation that describes the temperature without knowing the earth's temperature or the temperature of open space.   Your antenna has a field of view of 50 degrees.  The earth is only 5 degree wide.  That means your antenna "sees" the earth and open space.  So, it sees an average of two temperatues.  Each temperature has an effect on the antenna proportional to the portion of the field of view.  So, you have enough information to write an equation even if you can't put a number to it.

Comment: Once you have the equation, you can find the accepted standard values of the earth's temperature and the standard temperature of open space.  I found them easily enough, and I have never had cause to consider antenna temperature before in my life.

Comment: "You can find an equation that describes the temperature without knowing the earth's temperature or the temperature of open space." Kindly help for the formula ..

Answer (score 1):

Forget about formulas for a minute and reread the question. You have a satellite with an antenna aimed at the Earth. Make sure the Earth is all the antenna sees. In that case, the Earth has a known, accepted noise temperature.

Comment: In the question the noise temperature of earth is not given . So is data incomplete can be inferred ?

Comment: Not satisfied with the answer , needs formula based derivation of noise figure .

Comment: @nil then I don't know what you're doing dude. Your question and givens are about nothing but noise temperature. VTC

Comment: Need the way to know the actual formula/equation to calculate noise temperature of the antenna .

Comment: @nil You don't calculate the noise temperature of the Earth, it's a known constant.

Comment: Kindly help to solve this !!

Comment: We are all *very kindly* helping you to figure out how to solve your *homework problem*.  You are responding by jumping up and down and demanding complete answers, ready for you to write down without understanding.  You may be using the word "kindly", but you're still **demanding**, which makes the "kindly" worse than moot.  So **KINDLY** do your part, and take the *very generous hints* that you are getting, and **do some work** with them.

Comment: @NilabjaSaha: What are the results that you get when you do a Google or Wikipedia search on "noise temperature of the Earth"?

Comment: Noise temperature of earth is 290 K . It seems some data is missing .

Comment: @nil what data is missing? You have everything to answer your initial question